# Jenkins - Git fetch not fetching any branches

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

Newly setup jenkins isn't scanning any branches. I tried the global creds and multipipeline creds as well. The creds are regular http username and passwords.

[image]

Here is the log:

```
Started
[Tue Dec 08 16:12:29 UTC 2020] Starting branch indexing...
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.11.0'
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git ls-remote --symref -- https://gitlab.com/myusername/techworld-js-docker-demo-app.git # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Setting origin to https://gitlab.com/myusername/techworld-js-docker-demo-app.git
 > git config remote.origin.url https://gitlab.com/myusername/techworld-js-docker-demo-app.git # timeout=10
Fetching & pruning origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.11.0'
 > git config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress --prune -- origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
[Tue Dec 08 16:12:36 UTC 2020] Finished branch indexing. Indexing took 7 sec
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue was I only selected `Filter by name (regex)` but did not select `Discover branches`. Once I added that, it started working.

[image]